# Bash permission denied on Linux

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu

I was doing the "bof" problem on http://pwnable.kr/play.php
I downloaded the "bof" file. But when I use gdb, it says as follows:

```
Starting program: /home/henry/Downloads/bof 
/bin/bash: /home/henry/Downloads/bof: Permission denied
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /home/henry/Downloads/bof: cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

bof.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void func(int key){
    char overflowme[32];
    printf("overflow me : ");
    gets(overflowme);   // smash me!
    if(key == 0xcafebabe){
        system("/bin/sh");
    }
    else{
        printf("Nah..\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    func(0xdeadbeef);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure `bof` doesn't contain DOS line endings (e.g. `dos2unix /path/to/bof`) then make sure you have execute permissions (`chmod +x /path/to/bof`). And if you are using "Linux" under Win10 WSL, the file **must be located within the WSL filesystem**. NTFS has no concept of Linux file permissions. Howerver, `/home/henry/Downloads/bof` looks to be under a normal Linux FHS location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the issue with your **permissions**. You currently don't have the permissions to execute the bof file.

To fix this, open the terminal and use the `chmod` command.

```
chmod +x /home/henry/Downloads/bof
```

This will give you the permission to execute the file. You can also use something like `chmod 744 /path/to/file` as an alternative. This will give you the permission to read, write, and execute on your account.

Check out linode documentation to know about [file permissions](https://linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/).

Comment: but it showed "No such file or directory" after I used that method.

Comment: The generic command is `chmod +x /path/to/file`. You must modify `/path/to/file` depending on which directory you have that file. Are you sure you didn't mistype something? @Henry